# HTML form submitting values with multiple double quotes

Tags: java, html, forms, textarea, double-quotes

**HTML Code:**

```
<form action="...">
   <textarea name="str">"abc"</textarea>
</form>
```

**JS Code:**

```
 console.log($("textarea").val());   //output "abc" -> correct
 var v = $("textarea").val();   //adding a watch while javascript debugging to "v" shows ""abc""
```

Server side is written in java. Found that it receives value of textarea as `""abc""`.

When textarea is again populated with the saved value. i.e. upon refresh and some ajax implementation. It shows values as ""abc"". This seems to be a general and frequent scenario to me. But could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because your form's textarea will always load the ""abc"" when the same code is rerun again upon refresh.

What is the purpose for you to put ""abc"" as default in the text area though? Maybe you can consider using placeholder like this instead and leave the text area blank:

```
<form action="...">
   <textarea name="str" placeholder = "abc"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems the user is trying to fix the issue for any string. such as - This is a "textarea" will result into "This is a "textarea"".

Comment: Oh, yeah might be. I will delete my answer if it's not applicable to him.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about the ajax and any other code that runs at refresh?

It appears as though you might be adding in quotation marks when you take a value and store it into the textarea. This is purely a guess though, and may not be accurate depending on how things are set up. This is the first place I would look though.

Comment: @pravinautade I still do not see what is happening entirely. I think I am getting a better idea of the problem though. Are you saying that the value stored and the value it fills are the same, but the actual value sent was originally only single quotes? 

I would recommend just adding an action event handler that when the textarea changes or after the page loads, to check all fields and replace all double quotes with a single quote. 

I believe it is to escape the string so it isnt stored without the quotes initially, but is a nuisance it doesnt correct it after it is received server side